# Problems Submitting Form with FCKEditor on in MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, fckeditor

I've a bit of an odd issue with FCKEditor in my MVC project.

I've essentially got a View which renders a Partial View containing my FCKEditor (javascript, html and any other bits to make my control reusable throught my app)

I'm calling FCKEditor by doing the following:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/fckeditor/fckeditor.js") %>" type="text/javascript" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
    var sBasePath = '<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/fckeditor/") %>';

    var oFCKeditor = new FCKeditor('FckEditor1');
    oFCKeditor.BasePath = sBasePath;
    oFCKeditor.ReplaceTextarea();
}
</script>
```

To validate my form, I'm using jQuery.Validate with the following code:

```
    //FORM VALIDATION
    $("#NewPageForm").validate({
        errorContainer: "#errorblock-div1, #errorblock-div2",
        errorLabelContainer: "#errorblock-div2 ul",
        wrapper: "li",
        rules: {
            titleTxt: "required",
            FckEditor1: "required"
        },
        messages: {
            titleTxt: "You must enter a page title.",
            FckEditor1: "You must enter at least some content."
        },
        submitHandler: function (form) {
            form.submit();
        }
    });
```

Locally, when debugging my project, this works absolutely fine and throws up an error to the user when they leave the editor blank.

However, when I publish the application and run it from the server, whenever the editor has content in, the form won't validate, telling me that my FCKEditor control is empty, when it clearly isn't.

If I take away the validation, and submit the form with all the relevant boxes filled, the collection of `collection("FckEditor1")` is also empty, but again, running this locally works first time, every time.

I've had a search around and what seems to be happening is that my text area `<%= Html.TextArea("FckEditor1", New With {.name = "FckEditor1", .class = "required"})%>` isn't being populated with the content entered into the FCKEditor, even though this is the box that FCK is linked to.

The issue exists in all the browsers I've tried (IE8 and FF).

Not sure if it's also worth noting that FCK still renders fine too?

I'm not entirely convinced it's an issue with my code as it runs perfect locally. Is there anything I need to configure server-side or in web.config that could be causing it?

Has anyone else come across this or have any ideas as to how to solve the issue?

**EDIT**

I think I could be partway there with a fix.

I've added the following so far:

```
    $('#publishBtn').button().click(function () {
        if (typeof (FCKeditorAPI) == "object") {

            FCKeditorAPI.GetInstance("FckEditor1").UpdateLinkedField();

        } else {
            alert('this is not an object!');
        }

        if ($("#FckEditor1").val() == "") {
            alert("FCKEditor is empty");
        } else {
            $("#NewPageForm").submit();
        }
    });
```

Though, I now get sent to a blank page when the form is submitted, though nothing in my controller seems to be the issue - at least I don't think so as if there was an issue there, it'd do the same on my local machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the source of my problem, and it's to do with the way I'm handling multiple submit buttons in my controller.

I've tweaked it and it's now fixed.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that may be causing your issue if you are validating on the server is that once it's on IIS you cannot post HTML content without the request validation preventing the FCKContent from being passed. Cassini wont check this so it works on your local machine.

try adding this to your the action which is called when you post to validate:

```
[ValidateInput(false)] 
public ActionResult UpdateAction() 
{ 

}
```

Comment: Server-side is fine as I already have that in there, and like I say, it all runs fine, first time every time when debugging locally. I've not got the foggiest as to why though, the only difference I can see is that rather than it running as http://localhost:1234, the app runs as a virtual application under an IIS site, though I don't think that would cause that sort of behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried it as a non-virtual application on IIS? Also, I tend to run a copy of fiddler2 in these situations to compare the calls on each instance, looking at headers and post data to compare every call and return.

Comment: Yes, though the issue is still present. As for the post data, nothing seems to actually be in the textarea itself, it's also not returning anything server-side from the textarea.

Answer (score 0):

If possible, use CKEditor instead; it integrates with MVC much better.

http://ckeditor.com/

http://ckeditor.com/what-is-ckeditor

Comment: Unfortunately it's not an option due to the cost now incurred by the file manager part of the product, hence why we chose FCKEditor instead. Unless that has changed recently?

Comment: Additionally, I've tried the demo version to see if it resolves the issue, but it still exists with CKEditor. I don't think MVC is the issue here as it runs fine locally, the issue only occurs when I publish the app to the server.